# Spring boot war consuming lot of memory

Tags: spring-boot, war, tomcat8

I have a tomcat 8 instance on which I am running a standard J2EE application and memory utilization is low. We added a new Springboot application (.war) file on this same instance and we see that the memory consumed by this tomcat instance has been continously increasing.

To identify the root cause, we disconnected one of such node, such that no request reach this springboot application but we still see the memory continuously increasing.

This Springboot application does not have any cache set up. Is there any limitation or should I not deploy a springboot war with other traditional war applications?

Comment: i am also facing same issue while war file deployed on jboss and tomcat if you get something please let me know or if i find i will let u know

Comment: can you tell how much memory it is consuming ......

Comment: Could you try to replace you Spring Boot war by another Spring Boot app with simplest code like https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and monitoring if the memory is being consumed so far